# Safari 8 3rd party cookie not being sent

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies, safari, cross-domain

Domain A is loading domain B in an iFrame. In order for domain B to set a cookie in Safari (with "allow from current website only" configuration) we had to do some manipulations (user actions). However now the cookie isn't being sent (to domain B).

1. domain A opens domain b in an iframe
2. user clicks on a button, which opens a new tab with domain B
3. the cookie is being set. Safari is now set with a cookie from domain B.
4. in the iframe we do window.location.href="url to domain B" - the cookie isn't being sent.
   If I browse to the same URL in a different tab I do see the cookie being sent.

Has anyone encounter this as well? Any known solutions?

Answer (score 1):

In mobile advertising space, a few years back, when apple disabled the 3rd party cookie on mobile safari, google (DFP) came out with the workaround to bypass the restriction by creating iframe on the page and set the cookies there. It worked for a while till apple found out and blocked it. As far as I know, there is no workaround to enable 3rd party cookies on mobile safari.